# Python, как заблокировать или удалить переменную в определенной строке кода

Tags: python

Есть цикл for, в нем переменная n, которая в каждой итерации цикла меняется и может принимать разные значения, как пример - 3,  6,  1,  9.
n - это значение переменной в текущей итерации цикла,
n0 - это значение той же переменной, но в предыдущей итерации цикла.

Проблема в том, что есть переменная m = n + n0

n0 - заранее не известна, если бы цикл как то выполнил первую итерацию, дальше все пошло бы как по маслу. Если подставить перед вычислением m, n0 = 5, чтобы выполнить первую итерацию, то после первой итерации эту строку нужно как то заблокировать, иначе не даст находить значение n0:

```
for (опустим):
    n0 = 5  # после первой итерации заблокировать

    n = x * y
    m = n + n0

    global n0
    n0 = x * y
```

Возможно я не прав и есть более изящное решение для запуска цикла.

Comment: Так вынесите `n0 = 5` за пределы цикла. На первой итерации, n0 будет равно 5, а на следующих, значение переменной установится в теле цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легко:

```
n0 = None

for (опустим):
    # после первой итерации заблокировать
    if n0 is None:
        n0 = 5

    n = x * y
    m = n + n0

    ...
```